# jquery autocomplete dynamic textfield

Tags: jquery

I am using a jQuery plugin (autocomplete) here http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/ and I am adding dynamic text fields to a page which require the autocomplete feature.

Each text field has the same class and if possible would like to use the class i.e.

```
$(".liveSearchSuburb").autocomplete();
```

How would I go about re-init the plugin?

```
$("#btnAddAnotherLocation").live("click", function(){
    cloneIndexLocation++;
    $("#clonedInputLocation0").clone()
    .appendTo("#clonedInputsLocation")
    .attr("id", "clonedInputLocation" + cloneIndexLocation)
    .find("*").each(function(){
        var id = this.id || "";
        var match = id.match(regex) || [];
        if(match.length == 3){
            this.id = match[1]+(cloneIndexLocation);
        }
    }).end();
    $("#clonedInputLocation" + cloneIndexLocation).css("display", "inline");
});
```

Comment: There is no automatic way to do this, like for event delegation. You have to call the plugin on the field(s) you create. Can you show the piece of code that creates the fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For re-initializing autocomplete you could do something like:

```
("#textField").unbind().autocomplete("get_list.php", {...});
```

Check for ref: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Comment: $("#textField").unbind().autocomplete removes all values from previous fields. Do you know how to keep those values?